# SQL SELECT with table name in query

Tags: mysql

I have simple query:

```
$table_name = 'v_c_holi_2012';

$STH_h3 = $DBH_R->query("SELECT DATE(date_time) AS day_h

                          FROM `$table_name`
                     ");
```

and it is working ok.
But I must do this query with table name and when I try this:

```
$table_name = 'v_c_holi_2012';

$STH_h3 = $DBH_R->query("SELECT `$table_name`.DATE(date_time) AS day_h

                          FROM `$table_name`
                     ");
```

or

```
$table_name = 'v_c_holi_2012';

$STH_h3 = $DBH_R->query("SELECT v_c_holi_2012.DATE(date_time) AS day_h

                          FROM `$table_name`
                     ");
```

this is not working (Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object).

What I 'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `date` function should not have the `table` prefix since it is a system function.
Instead you need to put the table alias before your field `date($table_name.date_time)`.

By the way, you don't need to if you select from only one table.

Comment: thnks, I must do it from 2 tables, thnks. As I se, I'm only thinking that i 'm thinking ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe `$table_name.DATE(date_time)` should be `DATE($table_name.date_time)`

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the table name to the thing that's in the table (i.e. the field name), not the `DATE` function (which has nothing to do with your table).

i.e.

```
$table_name = 'v_c_holi_2012';

$STH_h3 = $DBH_R->query(
    "SELECT DATE(`$table_name`.`date_time`) AS `day_h`
    FROM `$table_name`"
);
```